# testing a not condition in a variable that has boolean value

Tags: shell, testing, if-statement, boolean, conditional-statements

I implicitly assign a Boolean to a variable

```
x=false
```

I can do this

```
 $x || echo "the value is set to true"
```

But the reverse test  isn't just that short and sweet

```
 { ! $x || echo "the value is set to false "  ; }
```

in Bourne  (Ksh ) it evaluates like

```
 ! false
```

and the results are not the same

So one could use a test value for the opp condition ( ! )

```
[ "$x"  = "true" ]
```

Is that the only short way to reverse test a boolean  or there is a better way to say it

Comment: `{ ! $x || echo "the value is set to true"; }` works fine in BASH/ksh

Comment: Anubhava. Welcome back and thanks 'again. Well -that i exactly what I used in the past but it did not give predictable results esp with conditions where you are 'anding' it so I changed to true

Comment: Make `x=true` and then call above to see if it prints. `! $x ||` means 2 negatives.

Comment: yes thx. My situation - I am setting flags to false before the case statement and then set them to true inside 'em

Comment: I will upd my Q in a sec

Comment: I thought you were going to update your question.

Comment: Yes Anubhava . Will do .Thanks for your patience . I want to create that specific situation why I left away with  that ! x option.

Comment: Sure take your time. Whenever you edit just leave a comment with @anubhava to alert me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you want to print something according to $x is true or false? If so, I think the following should work:

```
$x && echo "the value is true" || echo "the value is set to false "  ;
```

Comment: Thx.I want to test the opp of the boolean ` ! $x && echo "msg"`

Answer (score 0):

```
if ! $x 
 then
    YourThenCode
 else 
    YourElseCode
 fi
```

sample

```
$ x=true;if ! $x ; then echo "True if"; else echo "false if" ;fi
false if
$ x=false;if ! $x ; then echo "True if"; else echo "false if" ;fi
True if
```